# Listdensityplot sort of smooths the data when I don't want it

Tags: plotting, smoothing

I tried plotting a densityplot and it gives me an image what I expected. like this
[image]

but after a split second it kind of updates itself to

[image]

why is its dynamically smoothing itself? I want the first one. Anyone came across this problem before.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
Manipulate[ ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[i, {400, 3}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

If you go on to the next plots for a split second it changes to the first image and then to a second type.

Comment: Add `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` as an option to `ListDensityPlot`. That is what would be used to make the fast-updating versions shown during update by Manipulate, then defaulting to "Quality" when no more changes are made to the manipulate variables.

Comment: @MarcoB works great. Thanks